proximal operator of $z^{H}Az -2\Re\{b^{H}z\}$ . Where A is a positive semidefinite matrix of rank>1.
I would like to find a closed form solution to the proximal operator of the quadratic form $z^{H}Az-2\Re\{b^{H}z\}$, where A is psd and with rank>1.
The projection on this ellipsoid is rather straightforward to solve
\begin{equation}
\min_{z} ||z-z_0||^2_2 \\
s.t. z^{H}Az  -2\Re\{b^{H}z\} = c
\end{equation}
writing the Lagrangian and taking the derivative equal to 0  one gets a solution for z $U^{H}z = (I + μ\Lambda)^{−1} (U^{H}z_0 + \mu U^{H}b). $ with $A = U^{H}\Lambda U$, substituting this back into the equality constraint, we get a nonlinear equation in the Lagrange multiplier $\mu$ that can be solved by off-the-shelf root finding algos.
However this is on projection. An attempt at the prox operator I made is given below (although arguably the projection is a solution when the step size is very large).
My attempt here is to find either a closed form or a solution/approximation that is computationally light (I know I can use CVX to get the solution, but this won't fly in a realtime system).
The proximal operator with stepsize $t$ is $\def\prox{\mathop{\rm prox}\nolimits}\prox_tf \colon \mathbb C^m \to \mathbb C^m$ given by
$$ \prox_tf(x) = {\rm argmin}_{z \in \mathbb C^m} f(z) + \frac{1}{2t}\|x-z\|_2^2 $$
if I substitute for my problem I get $ \prox_tf(x) = {\rm argmin}_{z} 
 \left\{ z^{H}Az  -b^{H}z - z^{H}b + \frac{1}{2t}\|x-z\|_2^2 \right\}= \\ {\rm argmin}_{z} 
 \left\{ z^{H}Az  -b^{H}z - z^{H}b +\frac{1}{2t}\left(x^{H}x - x^{H}z - z^{H}x + z^{H}z \right)\right\} =  \\ {\rm argmin}_{z} 
 \left\{z^{H}(A+\frac{1}{2t} )z + (-\frac{1}{2t}x-b)^{H}z + z^{H}(-\frac{1}{2t}x-b) + \frac{1}{2t}x^{H}x \right\}$
Now probably the main thing is to notice that $A+ \frac{1}{2t}$ is pd, and this the minimum is unique (at least I hope I am correct about this).
taking a derivative with respect to $z^H$ and equating to $0$ we would get $(A+\frac{1}{2t} )z + (-\frac{1}{2t}x-b) = 0$ --> $z = (A+\frac{1}{2t} )^{-1}(b+\frac{1}{2t}x)$
thus $\prox_tf(x) = (A+\frac{1}{2t} )^{-1}(b+\frac{1}{2t}x)$
On the one side I am happy to have gotten rid of having to calculate the Lagrange multiplier from the projection, but the question is how to choose the step size (if this prox is even correct) when it's part of an iterative algorithm.

Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, etc.; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult this link for further guidance.

Closed-form solution may not be possible in general
